# check date_filename.txt exist

Tags: linux, centos6.5

I've created a set of linux command that do set of ping and keep the log file into 2 file, which is `date-time_successping` and `date-time_failping`. I want to do an action where when `date-time_failping` exist, the linux system will send an email to the PIC. but the filename is too random since i've a date infront of it. E.g. `20170911-160455_failping`. I tried using like `-c/-f`, but they cannot search if no specific name. there will be multiples of file with variant of dates created. So I need some advice on this. hope anyone could help.

thanks

P/S: I'm so sorry if the information that given is not enough, please reply if needed more info so that i could try to provide and help me solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: I just noticed. my file name is actually date-time_failping.txt..... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this optionally,

This command is to get yesterday date:

```
VAR1=`date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday"`
```

Or you want to work with today's date

```
VAR1=`date +%Y%m%d `
$file = VAR1`__failping`
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "My message" | mail -s subject user@gmail.com
else
    //Do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inotify` to monitor your log file creation event, then check if the file pattern match `xxxxx_failping`. Assume your log files are put in `ping_logs`, you can use the following script to monitor

```
$ inotifywait -rme create ping_logs/ |awk '{if($NF ~ /[0-9]+-[0-9]+_failping/) print $NF}'
```

Here just print the file name, you can change to your mailing action.